# XML not showing up after transformation with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking to get my data cleared up using XML transformation.

My Request XML:

```
<Schools>
<SchoolName>
  <name>ABC International, Wisconsin</name>
  <rank>1</rank>
</SchoolName>
<SchoolName>
  <name>XYZ Primary, Las Vegas</name>
  <rank>1</rank>
</SchoolName>
<SchoolName>
  <name>Ryan Academy, Wisconsin</name>
  <rank>1</rank>
</SchoolName>
<SchoolName>
  <name>Advanced Elementary, Houston</name>
  <rank>1</rank>
</SchoolName>
</Schools>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

      <xsl:for-each select="Schools/SchoolName[name[contains(text(),'Wisconsin')]and not(name[contains(text(),'Academy')])]">

    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        <xsl:value-of select="rank" /> 
      </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Ouput I get:
ABC International, Wisconsin1

Output I expect:

```
<Schools>
<SchoolName>
  <name>ABC International, Wisconsin</name>
  <rank>1</rank>
</SchoolName>
</Schools>
```

What should I fix in XSLT to accommodate this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to output XML then make sure you copy the nodes you are interested in or you create new ones, copying should suffice for your use case:

```
<xsl:template match="Schools">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="SchoolName[name[contains(.,'Wisconsin')]and not(name[contains(.,'Academy')])]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But be aware that client-side XSLT in the browser is not a good environment for XML -> XML transformation so run that code in your XML editor or IDE to see the XML result, a browser might only display text nodes.